# Scala mock polymorphic methods with implicit type tag

Tags: scala, unit-testing, scalamock

How to mock a polymorphic method with an implicit type tag parameter

```
val mockInterface = mock[SampleInterface]

trait SampleInterface {

  def fetchType[M <: Model : TypeTag]: Future[Unit]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(mockInterface.fetchType[SampleModel](_: TypeTag[SampleModel]))
    .expects(typeTag[SampleMode])
    .returning(Future.successful())
```